# Change array position and how to delete object instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

I figured out how to add and even modify an instance in an object array, but how would I go about changing slots "every new Student() would add a slot" so starts at slot 0 and can go up to 3. And also, how would I remove an instance of an array?

```
var Student = function (name, address, city, state, gpa) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    console.log(name, address, city, state, gpa);
};


var Student1 = [
    new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0]),
    new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0])
];

  Student1.push(new Student("Some Guy","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first entry in an Array you can use `shift()`. To remove the last entry in an Array you can use `pop()`. To remove any other element in an array you can use `splice(index,count)` with the first argument the index you want to remove at and the second argument 1:

```
var Students = [
    new Student("Some Guy1","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0]),
    new Student("Some Guy2","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0]),
    new Student("Some Guy3","Some address","some city","some state",[2.5,3.1,4.0])
];

var s2a = Students.splice(1,1); // after this line Students contains just Some Guy1 and Some Guy 3
var s3 = Students.pop(); // after this line Students contains just Some Guy1
var s1 = Students.shift(); // after this line Students is an empty array
```

Note that while `pop` and `shift` return the actual elements removed, `splice` returns an Array of removed elements, in your case an Array containing just the second student.

You can find a lot of information on Arrays and the methods mentioned above on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But what I understand is... you want to delete an existing object from an array. If my understanding is right, please try array.splice(index,howmany).

Example:

```
var Diseases = ["Malaria", "Plague", "AIDS", "Cancer"];
Diseases.splice(2,1);
```

Output: ["Malaria", "Plague", "Cancer"];

Once an element in an array is deleted, the following elements shifts its position automatically. Hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: I was reading another question that was similar but to swap out an instance say 0 and 3, where 3 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 3. I think the answer would need to be a function. var array = [a,b,c]; array.split(""); function swap(theArray, index1, index2) { var temp = theArray[index2]; theArray[index2] = theArray[index1]; theArray[index1] = temp; }  essentially creat a swapping function? Can't say if this would work though.